# Stopping the character from moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets, standards

So I'm using the unity standard assets pack and I was trying to figure a way to freeze the players location, at first I tried to freeze the players location using the rigidbody but the character was still able to walk. Next I tried to disable the script that allows the player to move but I cannot see the script is other scripts (when I use public script name variable name it doesn't show up as a script name.

Comment: any scripts to show?

Comment: Hi Ethan, please take the [tour] and read the [help], especially on how to ask questions; it may prevent your question from being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can’t see the script, I don’t have much to go off of, but I’m assuming you’re using some either Input.Horizontal and Input.Vertical, or Input.getKey() to do your things.

If you want to freeze the movement, you can simply wrap the function for movement that you are using in an if statement with some kind of bool that contains whether or not the player should be frozen.

Example:

```
If(!frozen){
Player.Position.x += 5;
}
```

Or something like that.
If you need to get the variable in another script you could do something like this (this is a rough example to try to explain it, syntax may not be perfect):

```
GameObject player;
 
Player.MoveScript.frozen = false;
```

Something like that.